# how to occupy click event with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, es6-promise

I am trying to use the click event within a promise, and everything works fine when the button is pressed once, but if I want to press the button more than once the event no longer works.

How could I solve this problem with promises or should I use callback for these cases?
thank you.

```
add() {
      
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if ( rowsTable.length == 0) reject("add fail data:",  rowsTable.length);
            else {
                for (let i = 0; i <  rowsTable.length; i++) {

                  {
                        document.getElementById("add_button").addEventListener( "click", function () {
                             
                            resolve(rowsTable[i]);
                        }, {once: false});
                   
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need promise for event listener.It is pretty straightforward that once promise is done you need to again call the promise.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are designed to wait for *a thing* which will happen in the future, not for multiple things.

For most cases, just using a callback is fine.

If you have complex needs where you want to have a promise-like object which you can pass around and allow multiple other functions to subscribe to then look into Observables (such as are implemented by [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview)) which are similar to Promises except are designed to deal with streams of events rather than single ones.